# How to Limit ServletListener to a Single Context?

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, jetty, servlet-listeners

I have a JSR-356 WebSocket application.  I use listeners to initialize it, so that I don't need to rely on jar scanning for annotations which slows down the startup.

For example, I use a `ServletContextListener` implementation that register the WebSocket's `EndPoint`:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    ServerContainer serverContainer = (ServerContainer) sce
        .getServletContext()
        .getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer");

    serverContainer.addEndpoint(MyEndPoint.class);
}
```

And then register that listener in the web.xml deployment descriptor:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>my.ServletContextListenerImpl</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The problem is that now that EndPoint is registered for all of the Web Contexts, which is not what I want.

How can I limit the listener to specific Contexts?  Or set "init params" on the listener via configuration that I can then inspect in my ServletContextListener and register the EndPoint only if it matches some init param?

Answer (score 1):

Each webapp is its own `ServletContext`, it wouldn't be possible to have a single servlet listener respond to multiple webapp contexts like that.

Something else is going on in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two contexts for a web application.
The one which is Global called **Application Context**, it is accessible to entire web application. And other is a **Servlet Config**, this is accessible to a particular servlet only.

When you want to limit your listener to particular context, then you should use the init-params of a servlet (i.e Servlet Config) to your particular servlets.

```
<servlet>
<description>This is config servlet</description>
<servlet-name>ConfigContext</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.configcontext.ConfigContext</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer</param-name>
  <param-value>servlet container</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ConfigContext</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ConfigContext</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Each servlet will have its won servlet config, so you have to add the init-param "javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer" to all those servlets that you want to limit